# Cannot convert Boolean to String

Tags: apex, string, boolean

I have a need to show the boolean value as string and I'm trying to convert boolean to string but its not coming along, here is what I have done so far:

try to convert using `String.valueOf` but does not work.

tried this:

```
boolean b = true;
system.debug('boolean to string: ' + string.valueOf(b));
```

I'm getting the following:

```
USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|boolean to string: true
```

But I want that to be in string like this `'true'`

I have also tried to concatenate by using single quote

```
<apex:variable var="sr" value="{!string.valueOf('"' + record.status + '"')}"/>
```

then got this error:

> Error Error: value="{!string.valueOf('"' + record.status + '"')}" EL
>   Expression Unbalanced: ... {!string.valueOf('"' + record.status +
>   '"')}  Error  Error: EL Expression Unbalanced: ... {!string.valueOf('"'
>   + record.status + '"')}

Comment: String.valueOf(b) *is* a string.

Comment: System.assert( ((Object)(String.valueOf(b)) instanceOf String );

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833054/best-approach-to-converting-boolean-object-to-string-in-java OR what @sebastin kessel mentioned!

Comment: You may want to simply explain what the problem is, not try to find a solution to a problem that might not even solve your problem. This is what we've come to call an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to format it differently than what you get out of `String.valueOf`, it is probably worth creating a method for it.

```
public static String wrapSingleQuotes(Boolean input)
{
    return (input == null) ? '' : '\'' + String.valueOf(input) + '\'';
}
```

Then you can do:

```
system.debug('boolean to string: ' + wrapSingleQuotes(b));
```

Same strategy would apply for parens, double quotes, etc.

In VF, you can simply use `outputText`:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!'\'' & myBoolean & '\''}" />
```

Comment: 1+ is there a way to do it on VFP instead of creating an apex method?

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
Boolean theBool = true;

String theString = (theBool) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

It's more verbose but it works.

PS: in the Debug Log you will not see strings in quotes, are you sure that the `String.ValueOf` method you called before is not already returning a string?

Comment: FWIW, your solution forgot about one of the three Boolean states: null. Personally, I'd just use the following: `String theString = ''+theBool;` This is the same as String.valueOf(theBool), won't crash on nulls, and is shorter than other solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't have used my own solution, tbh... I am still a bit surprised the OP says `string.ValueOf()` didn't work for him. I suspect he either wanted single quotes (which won't automatically be added) or erroneously expected them.